# Using decorators to redefine parameters in inner function

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decorator, python-decorators

I am pretty new to using Python decorators. I was wondering what is the best way to define a decorator function that redefines `skm.confusion_matrix` from

```
import sklearn.metrics as skm
def _true_negative_rate(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
    tnr, fpr, fnr, tpr = skm.confusion_matrix(
        y_true, y_pred.round(), sample_weight=sample_weight, labels=[0, 1], normalize="true").ravel()
    return tnr
```

to:

```
import sklearn.metrics as skm
def _true_negative_rate(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
    tnr, fpr, fnr, tpr = skm.confusion_matrix(
        y_true, y_pred.round(), sample_weight=sample_weight, labels=[0, 1], normalize="all").ravel()
    return tnr
```

The slight alteration that I would like to make is change the normalize flag in `skm.confusion_matrix` from `"true"` to `"all"`. Is this possible? If so, a thorough explanation would also be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: There's no reason for a decorator here. Just make `normalize` a parameter of `_true_negative_rate` and pass the argument straight to `skm.confusion_matrix()`.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering what is the best way to define a decorator function that redefines `skm.confusion_matrix`

Short answer: don't. That would not be how you use decorators.

What you should do is simply pass on an argument via `_true_negative_rate()`:

```py
import sklearn.metrics as skm

def _true_negative_rate(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None, normalize="all"):
    tnr, fpr, fnr, tpr = skm.confusion_matrix(
        y_true, y_pred.round(), sample_weight=sample_weight, labels=[0, 1], normalize=normalize).ravel()
    return tnr
```